# "Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/vhosts] does not exist" although I've created /var/www/vhosts?

Tags: apache-http-server

I've installed apache and config my virtual host on my CentOS 6.4.

But when i restart apache ( using this command : sudo service httpd restart ) it's warning me that "Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/vhosts] does not exist". I've check the directory /var/www/vhosts, it already created and permission is 0777. What wrong i did? any help please...

This is my virtual hosts configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts
  ServerName trien.cba
  ServerAlias trien.cba
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/trien.cba.error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/trien.cba.access.log common
  <Directory "/var/www/vhosts">
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Options -Indexes
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is the warning:

```
[root@test-cba ~]#sudo service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:              [  OK  ]
Starting httpd: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/vhosts] does not exist
Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/vhosts] does not exist
                             [  OK  ]
```

Comment: Only thing I can think of is `vhosts` is a file and not a directory.

Comment: Yeah, what ultrasawblade said.  Try `ls -ald /var/www/vhosts`

Comment: Not at all, my /var/www/vhosts/ is a directory :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following things...

- Grep for DocumentRoot in your conf and ensure that the spelling is correct and the folder exists.
- Check permission of your /var/www/vhosts. The apache user must have the permission to access it. (Give read permission to others)
- Try setting SELinux to permissive mode.  (type setenforce 0, it will change selinux mode to permissive temporarily )

Comment: Thank you.
I've tried this "Try setting SELinux to permissive mode. (type setenforce 0, it will change selinux mode to permissive temporarily )" and my apache can restart ok.

Comment: SO the problem is with your selinux context of the DocumentRoot. If you dont have any issue in turning selinux as permissive, then you may do it by editing the file /etc/selinux/config ...In that you can set it to permissive. this change will be a permanent change and it will be effective only after a reboot. Or if you want to sort this out keeping selinux as enforcing, then set the selinux context of the document root to httpd_sys_content_t . Please  mark my post as answer if you find it useful.